# SQL query is showing error with more than one join on same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

I have searched on StackOverflow and internet but did not found any solution to this issue.
I have a table like myTable in SQL Server 2008 R2 with these columns:
`person_id`,`city`,`addressType`,`line_num`,`textarea` and some other columns but these are not needed.
All fields are of type int but textarea is of type varchar(10).
A person can have multiple type of addresses in a city. Address can be big so each address type can have multiple line numbers. Address type 1 is home address, Address type 2 is office address and address type 3 is other address.
Example rows are given here

```
person_id|city|addressType|line_num|textarea
1        |1   |1          |0       |House no.
---------------------------------------------
1        |1   |1          |1       |10
---------------------------------------------
1        |1   |2          |0       |Building5
---------------------------------------------
1        |1   |2          |1       |Floor 1
---------------------------------------------
1        |1   |3          |0       |Factory
---------------------------------------------
1        |1   |3          |1       |no. 30
```

I need to show all type of addresses for a person in one row.Like this:

```
person_id|city|homeAddress |officeAddress    |otherAddress
1        |1   |House no.,10|Building5,Floor 1|Factory,no.30
```

I used join.
Join worked fine for address type 1 and address type 2.

Here is the query with single join which is working fine:

```
SET ANSI_PADDING ON;
SELECT DISTINCT homeAddress_person_id, homeAddress_city, homeAddress, officeAddress
FROM
/*Sub query for home address*/
(SELECT person_id AS homeAddress_person_id, city AS homeAddress_city,
/*Concatinating home address*/
STUFF((SELECT ',' + textarea FROM myTable WHERE person_id=ResultsFrom_myTable_For_homeAddress.person_id AND city=ResultsFrom_myTable_For_homeAddress.city AND addressType=ResultsFrom_myTable_For_homeAddress.addressType FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(4000)'),1,1,'') AS homeAddress
FROM myTable ResultsFrom_myTable_For_homeAddress WHERE person_id=1 AND addressType=1
GROUP BY person_id,city,addressType) ResultsFrom_myTable_For_homeAddress_outer

FULL OUTER JOIN
/*Sub query for office address*/
(SELECT person_id AS officeAddress_person_id, city AS officeAddress_city,
/*Concatinating office address*/
STUFF((SELECT ',' + textarea FROM myTable WHERE person_id=ResultsFrom_myTable_For_officeAddress.person_id AND city=ResultsFrom_myTable_For_officeAddress.city AND addressType=ResultsFrom_myTable_For_officeAddress.addressType FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(4000)')
,1
,1
,'') AS officeAddress
FROM myTable ResultsFrom_myTable_For_officeAddress
WHERE person_id=1 AND addressType=2
GROUP BY person_id,city,addressType) ResultsFrom_myTable_For_officeAddress_outer
ON ResultsFrom_myTable_For_homeAddress_outer.homeAddress_person_id=ResultsFrom_myTable_For_officeAddress_outer.officeAddress_person_id AND ResultsFrom_myTable_For_homeAddress_outer.homeAddress_city=ResultsFrom_myTable_For_officeAddress_outer.officeAddress_city
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF;
```

But when I add another join to show other address. It shows error **An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected** 
Here is the query with two join

```
SET ANSI_PADDING ON;
SELECT DISTINCT homeAddress_person_id, homeAddress_city, homeAddress, officeAddress, otherAddress
FROM
/*Sub query for home address*/
(SELECT person_id AS homeAddress_person_id, city AS homeAddress_city,
/*Concatinating home address*/
STUFF((SELECT ',' + textarea FROM myTable WHERE person_id=ResultsFrom_myTable_For_homeAddress.person_id AND city=ResultsFrom_myTable_For_homeAddress.city AND addressType=ResultsFrom_myTable_For_homeAddress.addressType FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(4000)'),1,1,'') AS homeAddress
FROM myTable ResultsFrom_myTable_For_homeAddress WHERE person_id=1 AND addressType=1
GROUP BY person_id,city,addressType) ResultsFrom_myTable_For_homeAddress_outer

FULL OUTER JOIN
/*Sub query for office address*/
(SELECT person_id AS officeAddress_person_id, city AS officeAddress_city,
/*Concatinating office address*/
STUFF((SELECT ',' + textarea FROM myTable WHERE person_id=ResultsFrom_myTable_For_officeAddress.person_id AND city=ResultsFrom_myTable_For_officeAddress.city AND addressType=ResultsFrom_myTable_For_officeAddress.addressType FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(4000)')
,1
,1
,'') AS officeAddress
FROM myTable ResultsFrom_myTable_For_officeAddress
WHERE person_id=1 AND addressType=2
GROUP BY person_id,city,addressType) ResultsFrom_myTable_For_officeAddress_outer
ON ResultsFrom_myTable_For_homeAddress_outer.homeAddress_person_id=ResultsFrom_myTable_For_officeAddress_outer.officeAddress_person_id AND ResultsFrom_myTable_For_homeAddress_outer.homeAddress_city=ResultsFrom_myTable_For_officeAddress_outer.officeAddress_city

FULL OUTER JOIN
/*Sub query for other address*/
(SELECT person_id AS otherAddress_person_id,city AS otherAddress_city,
/*Concatinating office address*/
STUFF((SELECT ',' + textarea FROM myTable WHERE person_id=ResultsFrom_myTable_For_otherAddress.person_id AND city=ResultsFrom_myTable_For_otherAddress.city AND addressType=ResultsFrom_myTable_For_otherAddress.addressType FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(4000)'),1,1,'') AS otherAddress
FROM myTable ResultsFrom_myTable_For_otherAddress WHERE person_id=1 AND addressType=3
GROUP BY person_id,city,addressType) ResultsFrom_myTable_For_otherAddress_outer
ON ResultsFrom_myTable_For_homeAddress_outer.homeAddress_person_id=ResultsFrom_myTable_For_otherAddress_outer.otherAddress_person_id AND ResultsFrom_myTable_For_homeAddress_outer.homeAddress_city=ResultsFrom_myTable_For_otherAddress_outer.otherAddress_city;
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF;
```

What is wrong in the above query?

Comment: Format your query, so it will be better readable

Comment: @Jens Queries are formatted. Is this more readable now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and conditional aggregation we can clean this query up and turn it into this:

```
with cte as (
  select
      person_id
    , city
    , addressType
    , address = stuff((
        select ',' + i.textarea
        from myTable i
        where i.person_id = t.person_id
          and i.city = t.city
          and i.addressType = t.addressType
        order by line_num
      for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(4000)'), 1, 1, '')
from MyTable as t
group by person_id, city, addressType
)
select
    t.person_id
  , t.city
  , homeAddress   = max(case when t.addressType = 1 then t.address end)
  , officeAddress = max(case when t.addressType = 2 then t.address end)
  , otherAddress  = max(case when t.addressType = 3 then t.address end)
from cte as t
where t.person_id = 1
group by t.person_id, t.city
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/RWIQ34896

returns:

```
+-----------+------+--------------+-------------------+----------------+
| person_id | city | homeAddress  |   officeAddress   |  otherAddress  |
+-----------+------+--------------+-------------------+----------------+
|         1 |    1 | House no.,10 | Building5,Floor 1 | Factory,no. 30 |
+-----------+------+--------------+-------------------+----------------+
```

Your question says that `addressType` 0 is home, but your query is using `addressType` 1. I believe you can make the proper adjustments for this query either way.

Comment: Thanks. Address type 1 is home. Question is updated.

Comment: This worked like magic. You are the saviour. I wish could give you 10 upvotes. Thanks for making me learn new things.